# How to change ListBox selection based on CheckBox status and vice versa?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, listbox, controls

I have a `ListBox` filled with status of some work. To make it easier it's static, so contains pre-defined values. And I have three `CheckBoxes`: **`all`**, **`open`** and **`closed`.**
What I want:
[image][image][image][image]

**1st problem:**
Using `CheckedChanged` events to update other controls I'm generating endless loops.

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(checkBox1.Checked)
    {
         checkBox2.Checked = true;
         //etc.
    }
    //etc.
}        
private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(checkBox2.Checked && checkBox3.Checked)
    {
         checkBox1.Checked = true; //this immediately triggers checkBox1_CheckedChanged
         //etc.
    }
    //etc.  
}
```

At this point it dies though I haven't event started to manage the 3rd `checkBox` and the `listBox`.

**2nd problem:**
This is basically the same endless loop issue, but the other way around. If the user selects only the first three items in the `listBox` I want none of the `CheckBoxes` to be checked but the `open`. This again triggers the `CheckedChange` event, which sets the `ListBox` selected items, which triggers `SelectedIndexChanged`... and so on. How shall I break this?

Comment: You get an endless loop because of checkBox2.Checked = true; in the checkBox2_CheckedChanged - remove it!

Comment: I know why I get the endless loop. I can't remove as both the open and closed are ticked, I have to tick the all checkbox as well. This is the issue itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the checked value without triggering the event simply remove the event handler and then re-apply it.

```
checkBox1.CheckedChanged -= checkBox1_CheckedChanged;
checkBox1.Checked = true;
checkBox1.CheckedChanged += checkBox1_CheckedChanged;
```

Apply this wherever you want to set Checked = true.

Comment: Are you saying that I can remove the event handler and then add it back within another event? Like: private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
checkBox1.CheckedChanged -= checkBox1_CheckedChanged;
checkBox1.IsChecked = true;
checkBox1.CheckedChanged += checkBox1_CheckedChanged;
}

Comment: Yes inside of your eventhandler in order to set IsChecked without triggering a CheckedChanged event you would need to remove the CheckedChanged eventhandler and then re-apply it after you've set IsChecked.

Comment: Let me try it. I'll get back soon.

Comment: This is perfect. To make it simple in all the events I remove all the other eventhandlers, do the necessary, and add them back. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

For the "All" check box, building off Matt's answer, I would use the following as checkBox1's CheckedChanged event...

```
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkBox2.CheckedChanged -= checkBox2_CheckedChanged;
        checkBox3.CheckedChanged -= checkBox3_CheckedChanged;
        checkBox2.Checked = checkBox1.Checked;
        checkBox3.Checked = checkBox1.Checked;
        checkBox2.CheckedChanged += checkBox2_CheckedChanged;
        checkBox3.CheckedChanged += checkBox3_CheckedChanged;
        // etc.
    }
```

This way, if you click the All check box it will both check and uncheck the other 2 boxes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the `CheckedChanged`-event. Try changing it to `Click`-event, and change the code as neccessary.